# docker x509 certificate signed by unkown authority

Tags: ssl, docker, proxy

I'm an absolute Beginner in Docker and install on my workstation ubuntu 16.04.3 the latest docker version successfully.

But when I now try to do following:
docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
Pulling repository docker.io/library/hello-world
docker: Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.
See 'docker run --help'.

I got the issue with the x509 error message.

We have in our company a firewall and I have already copied our company root certificate to /etc/docker/certs.d/ 
We also use a internet proxy for communication to the internet, so i configured the daemon who starts with systemd, I set the environment for the http proxy and https proxy but still get the same x509 error message.

Could somebody please help me.

thank you

$ docker -v
Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802

Comment: Did you load the root cert into the OS?

Comment: Did you complete the steps described in https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#httphttps-proxy?

Comment: yes, I completed the http/https proxy settings for the dockerdaemon with systemd

Comment: no, I don't load the root cert into the OS? I can try this on monday, when I'm back in my office

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with the update-ca-certificates: copy the root cert file into /usr/local/share/ca-certificates and run update-ca-certificates manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/…

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but what solved the issue for me was to get libxssl.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libxss1
```

Comment: This problem seems to be quite insolvable. I'm having the same problem in Xubuntu 20, and I've tried absolutely all solutions out there, official and non-official. The only thing I haven't done is install a local certificate server on my workstation. But that's so stupid that it's not an option.