# gitalb CI: x509: certificate signed by unkown authority while accessing private docker registry

Tags: gitlab-ci, docker-swarm, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-registry

Can't login to my private docker registry from the gitlab-ci.

**Scenario:**

1. gitlab CE omnibus installation, the registry is inside the gitlab.
2. gitlab-runner with docker executor running as container in a docker swarm cluster
3. gitlab-runner has a ca.crt in /etc/gitlab-runner/certs/
4. The ca.crt contain the server, the intermediate and the root certificate in the correct order.
5. It's not a sel-signed certificate, it's a wildcard certificate (*.domain.com)
6. Inside the gitlab-runner container I can run `curl https://registry.domain.com` without erro

**What I have tried:**

- Add the registry as insecure (daemon.json and in the .gitlab-ci.yaml)
- Add the certificate in the runner as registry.domain.com.crt

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
build_image:  
  image: docker:19.03.8
  services:
    - name: docker:19.03.12-dind
      command: ["--insecure-registry=registry.domain.com:443"]
      alias: docker
  stage: build
  ...
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.domain.com
```

obs: I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47205727/docker-x509-certificate-signed-by-unkown-authority) without success.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what caused this issue but the solution was mount docker socket in the gitlab-runner

`gitlab-runner register <other_options> --docker-volumes /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`